# Access Twitter ads API using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I need to integrate **Twitter ads API** into my PHP application.
Application only authentication is successful, But single user authentication is not success.
I am using Abrahams PHP twitteroauth Library.

```php
<? php namespace Abraham\TwitterOAuth;
    include "autoload.php";
    const CONSUMER_KEY = "**********************************";
    const CONSUMER_SECRET = "*************************************";
    $oauthToken = "****************************************";
    $oauthTokenSecret = "**************************************";

    function getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
        return $connection;
    }

    $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
    $content = $ connection - > get("statuses/home_timeline");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($content); 
?>
```

Getting an error.

```
> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
> 'Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'name
> lookup timed out' in /var/www/tauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:346\nStack
> trace:\n#0 /var/www/tauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php(277):
> Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\TwitterOAuth->request('https://api.twi...',
> 'GET', 'Authorization: ...', Array)\n#1
> /var/www/tauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php(248):
> Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\TwitterOAuth->oAuthRequest('https://api.twi...',
> 'GET', Array)\n#2 /var/www/tauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php(177):
> Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\TwitterOAuth->http('GET', 'https://api.twi...',
> 'statuses/home_t...', Array)\n#3 /var/www/tauth/index1.php(16):
> Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\TwitterOAuth->get('statuses/home_t...')\n#4
> {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/tauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 346
```

**Please help me to access Twitter ads API.**

Answer (score 0):

Codebird-PHP 3.0.0, which is now in beta, supports accessing the Ads API. It looks like this:

```php
$reply = $cb->ads_accounts_ACCOUNT_ID_cards_appDownload([
  'account_id' => '123456789',
  'name' => 'Test',
  'app_country_code' => 'DE'
]);
```

#### Multiple-method API calls

In the Twitter Ads API, there are multiple methods that can be reached by HTTP GET, POST, PUT and/or DELETE. While Codebird does its best to guess which HTTP verb you’ll want to use, it’s the safest bet to give a hint yourself, like this:

```php
$reply = $cb->ads_sandbox_accounts_ACCOUNT_ID_cards_imageConversation_CARD_ID([
  'httpmethod' => 'DELETE',
  'account_id' => '123456789',
  'card_id' => '2468013579'
]);
```

Codebird will remove the httpmethod parameter from the parameters list automatically, and set the corresponding HTTP verb.

More info on Codebird-PHP & download at:

https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php

(Be sure to download a 3.x version or newer.)